# No Animation with a React-Pose and NextJS combination

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I want in my current project some fancy animations. My tool of choice was [React-Pose](https://popmotion.io/pose/). As a SSR framework i use [NextJs](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/) with [styled-components](https://www.styled-components.com/). So my problem now is that react-pose doesn't play any animations when everything is fully rendered on Client side. Due to some forum post it is possible to use react-pose with nextjs (I is speculated even the react-pose site itself is made with nextjs). Here one of my Components:

```
import posed from "react-pose";
import styled from "styled-components";

const Animation = posed.div({
  exit: {
    x: "-100%",
    delayChildren: 200,
    staggerChildren: 50
  },
  enter: {
    x: "0%",
    delay: 300
  }
});

const SidebarContainer = styled(Animation)`
  width: 300px;
  height: 100vh !important;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 20px;
`;

const ChildrenContainer = posed.div({
  exit: {
    y: 0,
    opacity: 0
  },
  enter: {
    y: 20,
    opacity: 1
  }
});

const Sidebar = props => (
  <SidebarContainer>
    <ChildrenContainer>{props.children}</ChildrenContainer>
  </SidebarContainer>
);

export default Sidebar;
```

Can anyone help me here?